# Bulk change import from one package to different one

Tags: reactjs, vscode-extensions, chmod

In one of my projects, I have to make some changes in the import.

For example, currently, the import looks like this

```
import { Row, Button, Col } from "reactstrap"
```

and I want to change it to

```
import { Row, Col } from "reactstrap"
import { Button } from "@components/button";
```

Manually it's going to take lot of time, and there are other imports apart from this, so looking for better solutions. I have checked jscodeshift but I couldn't make it work with this update.

Is there any VSCode extension related to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with normal find and replace in VS code. It is worked for me.

[image]